# C++ Nested Loop not giving me any values

Tags: c++, loops, generator, nested-loops

So this nested loop is supposed to generate random scores of 10 exercises for each
student that the user typed in. After the scores are generated it has to add them all up and find the average score. However when I run the program it doesn't give me any values. Here's the code:

```
int progExAvg, progExScore, studentAmt;
int counter = 0;
int progExTotal = 0;

srand(time(0));

cout << "Please enter how many students do you have in your class: ";
cin >> studentAmt;
cin.sync();

while (counter < studentAmt)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        progExScore = rand() % 100 + 1;
        progExTotal = progExTotal + progExScore;
    }

    progExAvg = progExTotal / 10;



}
cout << progExAvg << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: You never increment `counter`. so the while loop will never terminate

Answer (score 1):

You never increment `counter`, so its always less than `studentAmt`

```
while (counter < studentAmt)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        progExScore = rand() % 100 + 1;
        progExTotal = progExTotal + progExScore;
    }

    progExAvg = progExTotal / 10;

    counter++;

}
```

Comment: Ha yeah that was it. I'm now getting values back but they're way too big (1167 just now). Any idea what else is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Move these declarations

```
int progExTotal = 0;
int progExTotal = 0;
```

and this statement

```
cout << progExAvg << endl;
```

inside the while loop

And this declaration

```
int progExScore;
```

inside the for loop

Take into account that it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like 10. It is better to use meaning names.

Also you have to increase variable counter. For example

```
const int TOTAL_EXERCISES =  10;

while (counter++ < studentAmt)
{
    int progExTotal = 0;
    int progExTotal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_EXERCISES; i++)
    {
        int progExScore = rand() % 100 + 1;
        progExTotal = progExTotal + progExScore;
    }

    progExAvg = progExTotal / TOTAL_EXERCISES;

    cout << progExAvg << endl;
}
```

Comment: Like bzhag reminded me I incremented the counter and as you suggested I moved the progExTotal declaration inside the loop. I'm no longer getting crazy high values back. Thanks a lot